# How to improve performance of a loop in python

Tags: python, performance, cython

I have a problem that I need to interate over a big list and find the first True condition, if I use filter and list built-in functions  it is faster but have to complete the iteration or I use traditional 'for' that can return in the first True condition.
But it have almost same time to complete, here some example.

```
def for_first_true_1(l_list, string):
    for x in l_list:
        # may be a more complex logic
        if string in x:
            return True
    return False
```

The example above is slower in execution time but faster in logic

```
def for_first_true_2(l_list, string):
    def has_string(x):
        if string in x:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    value = list(filter(has_string, l_list))
    return bool(value)
```

The example above have more calls once it have to iterate over the whole list, but is more efficient.

The result is both have almost the same time to complete.

The list had about 100 elements
The result below is based on original code that I can't expose:

```
# equivalent of for_first_true_2
RUNNING TIME: 0.0005581378936767578
909 function calls (906 primitive calls)

# equivalent of for_first_true_1
RUNNING TIME: 0.0004608631134033203
264 function calls (261 primitive calls)
```

How do I improve performance of the for loop?

What I have thinking as alternative?

1 - Build a cython operation, but I don't know how:
It have a list of strings(ll), and the func is the python function to be called

```
def bool_for_loop(func, ll: list, arg: str) -> bool:
    value = False
    for x in ll:
        value = func(x, arg)
        if value:
            return True
    return False
```

something like

```
def for_first_true_cython(l_list, string: str):
    def has_string(x):
        if string in x:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return  bool_for_loop(has_string, l_list)
```

The any does't seems to be that optimized

Comment: Have you tried `any()`?

Comment: I highly doubt that `for_first_true_2` is more efficient. What's your benchmark code/results?

Comment: You could try itertools first_true which does exactly this.

Comment: Ideally, your benchmark makes it easy to include further solutions we come up with.

Comment: *"The result below is based on original code that I can't expose"* - Well, then make up equivalent code that you *can* share. If we have alternative solution ideas but don't know how to test them, how can we know whether they're any good?

Comment: timings also depend on where the true is found, at start or near the end.

Comment: What makes the execution slow is mainly the overhead of CPython. On top of that adding function calls can slow things down even more although `filter` is quite optimized. Cython can help if you know the **precise types**. `list` is not a precise type. It is a partial one : what is the type of the list's items? What is the type of `func`? Without the types, Cython will only barely make things faster. It will just remove the interpreter overhead but not the other ones related to CPython (type checking, function calls, reference counting, etc.).

Comment: Put it shortly, please provide a minimal *reproducible* example.

Comment: The slowest part of your code is likely to be the if-statement, not the for-statement. If your actual logic is more complex, it is more likely to be. So, please provide actual logic as well.

Comment: @ken Right, I just tested their example with `l_list, string = [''] * 100, 'a'` and got times over 100 times faster than theirs. So apparently their condition costs more than 99% of the time.

Comment: Just an idea: What if you use `filter`, but instead of obediently returning true or false, you just throw an exception when a match occurs. Then you catch the exception and return `True`, or return `False` if no exception occurred. This probably combines the performance of `filter` with the breaking out if the condition is met early on.